# Can I show the native Ubuntu package version of a program for that a never version is installed from a PPA?

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, stable-release-updates

So lets say I have a beta version of a program installed via PPA and want to know the version of the official version that ships with Ubuntu.

The only way I know is going to the Ubuntu package search website and searching for the package.

Is there a simple console command to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below command,

```
apt-cache policy package-name
```

Example 1:

```
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ apt-cache policy firefox
firefox:
  Installed: 24.0+build1-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 27.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.13.10.1
  Version table:
     27.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.13.10.1 0
        500 http://ubuntu.inode.at/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ubuntu.inode.at/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 24.0+build1-0ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ubuntu.inode.at/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In the above example, the saucy main repository provides only the version  `24.0+build1-0ubuntu1` but `http://ubuntu.inode.at/ubuntu/ saucy-updates/main amd64 Packages` and `http://ubuntu.inode.at/ubuntu/ saucy-security/main amd64 Packages` provides the latest version(`27.0.1+build1-0ubuntu0.13.10.1`) of firefox.

Example 2:

```
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ apt-cache policy vlc
vlc:
  Installed: 2.0.8+git20140211+r49186+13+8~ubuntu13.10.1
  Candidate: 2.0.8+git20140305+r49188+13+8~ubuntu13.10.1
  Version table:
     2.0.8+git20140305+r49188+13+8~ubuntu13.10.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.0.8+git20140211+r49186+13+8~ubuntu13.10.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.0.8-1 0
        500 http://ubuntu.inode.at/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
```

In this example both videolan PPA and Universe repository provides the same version of vlc.

Comment: ~ ~ S w e e t ~ ~